# jqplot: special scale graphs options

Tags: jqplot

I use jqplot to draw a graph. I have a huge difference between point values: point a is 2, point 2 is 5, point 3 is 500, point 4 is 10.

The jqplot scale system builds correct the graph, but because of such big difference the smaller values are represented as tiny lines, almost not visible on the graph (point a is not visible, point b is a tiny line).

[image]

In order to better see the values representation I'd like to build soemething like this (photoshop image, not jqplot render):

Example:

[image]

Is any way to do this? I don't even know how is called this option, but I know I saw in some graphs something like this. Do I have an option in jqplot to enable this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your y-axis as a logarithmic axis :

```
axes: {
  yaxis:{ 
    renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer
  }
}
```

after having included this file : `<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.(min.)js"></script>`

You can find an example [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/dateAxisLogAxisZooming.html), and some documentation [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-logAxisRenderer-js.html)

Comment: This is a good way to do this, but I lose details on closest values: if I have  {a: 5, b: 6, c: 300, d: 4}, then log 4 ~ log 5 ~ log 6.

Comment: Have you try to play with **base** and **tickDistribution** options ? [see documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-logAxisRenderer-js.html). Not sure it can solves something

Comment: I didn't try to play with those. But I will.